# Как устранить выбросы в датафрейме?

Tags: python, dataframe, float

Имеется датафрейм student со стобцом Fedu:
4.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0 и т.д.
Пытаюсь устранить выбросы:

```
q3 = student.Fedu.quantile(q = 0.75, interpolation = 'midpoint')
q1 = student.Fedu.quantile(q = 0.25, interpolation = 'midpoint')
IQR = q3 - q1
a = q1 - 1.5*IQR
b = q3 + 1.5*IQR
student.Fedu = student.Fedu.apply(lambda x: x[(x>a) & (x < b)])
```

Выдает ошибку: TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

Вопрос: как устранить выбросы? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
student.Fedu = student.Fedu[(student.Fedu>a) & (student.Fedu < b)])
```

После этого вместо удаленных значений выбросов у вас появятся значения NaN,
можно либо удалить строки с данным значением с помощью метода .dropna(axis = 0, inplace = True), либо заполнять данные значения с помощью метода .fillna()

Comment: Вместо каких удалённых значений?

Comment: Ну смотрите, если присвоить колонке student.Fedu отфильтрованные значения, как показано в коде, то вместо отфильтрованных значений будут NaN

Comment: @Nikolay, спасибо! Можно еще вопрос: как потом интерпретировать эти данные? Т.е. не очень понятно, считать дисперсию и стандартное отклонение до или после удаления выбросов?

Comment: Ну если вы пришли к выводу, что выбросы в ваших данных - это какие-то ошибочные и недостоверные данные, и вы решили их удалить, то и считать статистические показатели стоит после их удаления.